# Need help $PATH and terminal commands relink - no sudo, ps, grep

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, path

I had to change some path settings to install node.js in turn I must have edited a file that removed the path from the correct directory, whereby sudo, ps, grep etc. live. I am not sure how to reset this and what is the default order:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This is obviously incorrect as there is no sbin, or anything.

Note *
I cannot see the files because `default` doesn't work so cannot make it visible.

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `PATH` is as follows. Your requirements may differ but this `PATH` setting will at least give you shells and tools such as bash, sudo, etc.

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:`

to apply PATH settings:

`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:`

Comment: How would I go about changing it? Without nano that is?

Comment: I did it using `export PATH=` then above. Thanks :)